# How far can something travel in a straight line?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

Suppose you have an object some distance from you and moving at a velocity different to the Hubble velocity you'd expect at that point. How does the motion of this object change with time? Does it travel in a straight line (i.e. geodesic), and if you wait long enough how far will it get?

Comment: This question is fundamentally flawed, for at least a couple of reasons. (1) The expansion of the universe is not a velocity. It has units of velocity/distance, or inverse time. (2) It is essentially asking "What do the laws of the physics say will happen to a particle that doesn't obey the laws of physics?"

Comment: I amended the question to some degree. Would you be able to answer it now it?

Comment: You got rid of the "at the speed faster than the expansion of universe" part of the question. You did not fix the main problem. Physicists steer clear of immovable object versus irresistible force types of questions, and that's what you are asking.

Comment: I don't agree with David's objection. Your question is asking what the geodesic looks like for a body moving at some velocity relative to the comoving frame, and this seems to me a perfectly reasonable question and quite an interesting one.

Comment: @JohnRennie Could you edit the question to make the wording more suitable and precise, reflecting what you commented above?

Comment: MHOOS: I've attempted a rewording that retains the spirit of your question, but it's quite a radical change. If you don't like my edit please roll it back.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Many thanks for your edit. Hopefully your amendment will attract some reasonable answer.

Answer (score 5):

As for the straight line, yes. All objects will continue moving along geodesics (a straight line in curved-space but sometimes a curved line in straight-space) if there are no external forces acting on them. Unless, by different velocity you mean the direction is not entirely radial to us. In that case, the expansion will cause the object's path to appear to "bend" away from us, but this is still a geodesic for the object.

As for how far it will get, this depends on your distance measurement. In proper distance (the distance you would measure with a ruler), the object can get infinitely far away if you wait an infinite amount of time. There is no limit in proper distance. There is also something called comoving distance, which factors out the expansion of the universe. Two points that are only getting farther apart because the universe is expanding remain the same distance apart in comoving coordinates. In this distance measure, there is a fixed distance that the object can get to. The image below shows the maximum comoving distance that we can reach at different velocities.

[image]

The blue, purple, green, and black lines are 0.5c, 0.8c, 0.99c, and c respectively.

Today, comoving distance equals proper distance. So the distances you see on that graph are essentially the maximum today-distances you could reach (even though the actual distance travelled would be substantially larger). Anything beyond those distances are unreachable from where we are now. Anything at those distances would take 70 billion years to reach at the given velocities.

So you see, an object would travel along a geodesic path and a ruler would measure it going an unlimited distance, but there is a limit on how far something can travel on a comoving scale. And that is the more useful thing to know.

Comment: Just a caveat: the comoving distance to a place is the proper distance to that place TODAY, but it's not the proper distance you will be from home when you get there.  What the limiting distance of that black line really is is the distance to the cosmological horizon today.

Comment: Does this plot assume the current Hubble constant, but no acceleration?

Comment: @CuriousOne There is accelerated expansion, but it assumes a constant hubble constant